# boto3 Create non-expiring URLS

Tags: python, python-2.7, boto3

In boto3, there is a function that generate to generate pre-signed-urls, but they time out.
See: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.generate_presigned_url

Is there a way to create non-pre-signed URLS that do not expire?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to create non-pre-signed URLs or pre-signed URLs without expiration. The basic use of presigned URLs is

> A pre-signed URL gives you access to the object identified in the URL,
>   provided that the creator of the pre-signed URL has permissions to
>   access that object. That is, if you receive a pre-signed URL to upload
>   an object, you can upload the object only if the creator of the
>   pre-signed URL has the necessary permissions to upload that object.
>
> All objects and buckets by default are private. The pre-signed URLs
>   are useful if you want your user/customer to be able upload a specific
>   object to your bucket, but you don't require them to have AWS security
>   credentials or permissions. When you create a pre-signed URL, you must
>   provide your security credentials, specify a bucket name, an object
>   key, an HTTP method (PUT for uploading objects), and an expiration
>   date and time. The pre-signed URLs are valid only for the specified
>   duration.

The maximum expiration you can set to seven days i.e. 604800 seconds .

Please [check here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html) for more info.

Please check **X-Amz-Expires** in table present in above link.

Comment: thank you for the information! exactly what I needed.